Saving IMAQ image as PNG in MongoDB and exporting it with Python
I am aquiring image data with the LabView IMAQ module.
I convert the acquired image to a png string with IMAQ Write String VI and store that string in a MongoDB database.
If I fetch this string back from the database, write it to a file with Write to Binary File VI and read that file with IMAQ Read from File, I can display that image.
I can also open the created png file in Windows without problems.
Mock up VI
The string gets send to a REST API written in Python.
There I encode the string in utf-8 and store it in gridfs of my MongoDB instance.
I can fetch the png string from the database in LabView without problems and write it into a binary file with the LabView internal vis. I can open this image without problems.
But I want to be able to access those images from Python as well without going the route via LabView.
If I fetch the png string from the database through the REST API, where the string gets decoded from utf-8 and send it to Python via the requests.get method and do basically the same procedure to write the string to a binary file with:
raw_string_from_db = 'pngstringdata'
encoded_data = raw.encode('utf-8')
with open('test.png', 'wb') as png_file:
    png_file.write(encoded_data)

I can't open the image in windows or display it in any other way. I have tried converting it to base64, latin1, cp1252, and probably 10 more different encodings, nothing helps.
I also tried writing the string directly to a text file, doesn't work either.
Does anybody have an idea what might be the problem here?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Why are you UTF-encoding/decoding anything? It's binary, not text.
